# jqGrid bug with filtering small numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Merry Christmas!

I recently encountered a bug trying to filter small numbers with jqGrid. I'm filtering numbers that can range in magnitude from 10, to 1, to 10^(-8) or smaller. I find that it filters these numbers fine... until they become less than 10^(-6).

What's so interesting about that number? Check out the following output from my console (Chrome):

```
>e6=.000001
 0.000001
>e7=.0000001
 1e-7
```

It's the point when the browser (or JavaScript) starts using scientific notation.

Without further adieu, here's the code that demonstrates the bug.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var smallnumbers = {
        values: [
            {value: 100, text: "100"},
            {value: 10, text: "10"},
            {value: 1, text: "1"},
            {value: .1,  text: "10^(-1)"},
            {value: .01, text: "10^(-2)"},
            {value: .001, text: "10^(-3)"},
            {value: .0001, text: "10^(-4)"},         
            {value: .00001, text: "10^(-5)"},
            {value: .000001, text: "10^(-6)"},   
            {value: .0000001, text: "10^(-7)"},   
            {value: .00000001, text: "10^(-8)"},   
            {value: .000000001, text: "10^(-9)"},   
            {value: .00000000001, text: "10^(-10)"},
        ]
    };

    var myfilter = {
        groupOp: "OR",
        rules: [
            {field: 'value', op: 'lt', data: 1}
        ]
    };

    var grid = $('#demo').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        colNames: ['Value', 'Text'],
        colModel: [
        {
            name: 'value',
            index: 'value',
            width: '100'
        },
        {
            name: 'text',
            index: 'text',
            width: 100
        }
        ],
        data: smallnumbers.values,
        width: 500,
        height: '100%',
        pager: '#pager',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Bug with filtering small numbers',
        search: true,
        postData: {
            filters: myfilter
        }
    });
});
```

JavaScript is able to perform branching statements on numbers smaller than 10^(-6), as demonstrated below:

```
> if (e7 < 1) { console.log("This should appear"); }
This should appear
> if (e7 > 1) { console.log("This should not appear"); }
>
```

But it seems jqGrid isn't!

What gives? One workaround for this bug is to round small numbers up, as long as the bound will always be greater than what they round to. But I'd still like to know what is happening. Time to look at the source code...

Comment: Is the problem with jqGrid or whatever is providing the data? If the latter, then it may be fixable with `.toFixed(n)`, where n is pre-calculated for each value individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out the solution: adding sorttype: 'float' to each column in colModel.